# How to create one hotkey for two main languages, another hotkey for not-often-used language in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, language, hotkeys, input-languages, japanese

I'm using windows 8.1.
I use 3 languages(English, Thai, Japanese).
But I use English and Thai most of the time.
I change the language by pressing Lalt+Rshift.
The problem is I need to press two times to change from Thai to English.
(say input orders are Engish, Thai, Japanese)

I want to set Lalt+Rshift for changing only between English and Thai 
and some special hotkey, like Lalt+Lshift for changing to Japanese.

Is that possible? or are there any solution to this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  You can assign simple scripts to any key, key-combo, etc.  Its very powerful.